# How to make Angular JS Multiselect Dropdown Filter select the data on the table?

Tags: angularjs, servicenow

I have built the  simple list with with two drop downs, for example category drop down and subcategory dropdown. When you select the value from category i.e software then only the records containing the software category will be displayed. And when you select Email subcategory only the records containing this two values will be displayed.

The requirement has changed and now I should have the ability to select multiple values from category  i.e software and database from  the same column. Upon this selection data in a table should  be displayed containing only software and database.

I have built the Angular JS dropdown multilselect but I am having trouble connecting it to the table.

When I load the data with the filter applied I get the list of objects

I think I need to use the id from the client  script to select the object that  I want to display but I don't know how.

When I click on the multilselect all ids from the client scripts get attached to each object:

Any help much appreciated!!!

```
    function($scope) {
      /* widget controller */
      var c = this;

        $scope.example1model = [];
        $scope.example1data = [
                                                    {id: 1, label: "software"}, 
                                                    {id: 2, label: "database"}, 
                                                    {id: 3, label: "hardware"}
        ];

        $scope.filterTable = function(row){
            var right = false;
        console.log(row,$scope.example1model)
            if($scope.example1model){
                Object.keys($scope.example1model).forEach(function(val){
                    if(row.notes_category == val.label)
                        right = true;
                        //return label;
                })
            }
            else

            //  right = true
         return right;
        }


    }
```

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div ng-dropdown-multiselect=""  options="example1data" selected-model="example1model"></div>
            </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    </nav>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <!-- Default panel contents -->
      <div class="panel-heading">Data</div>

      <!-- Table -->
      <table class="table">
         <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Title</th> 
        <th>Notes category</th>
        <th>Notes Subcategory</th>
        <th>Note</th>
        <th>Notes Contact Type</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>User</th>


      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="note in data.notes | filter:filterTable">
        <td>{{note.number}}</td>
        <td>{{note.title}}</td> 
        <td>{{note.notes_category}}</td>
        <td>{{note.notes_subcategory}}</td>
        <td>{{note.note}}</td>
        <td>{{note.notes_contact_type}}</td>
        <td>{{note.state}}</td>
         <td>{{note.user}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I expect to use id from $scope.example1data to control the data on the table

Comment: Add your html code too. It is not very clear what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks very much. I added the HTML code as well